# setAttribute with javascript inside a for evaluation

Tags: javascript, evaluation, setattribute

I am trying to set attribute for an element.

the element is pulled from a class (active) and assigned a variable.  The same element is pulled from a different class (topArrow) and assigned a variable.

When comparing the two variable to run an if statement the evaluate as not the same...???

console.log to see what is going on and I get this:

```
HTMLCollection[img.active images/a.../top.png]
HTMLCollection[]
```

where as on an element that does not have a class of topArrow i get this:

```
HTMLCollection[img.active images/a...left.png]
HTMLCollection[img.topArrow images/a.../top.png]
```

---

```
    var arrow = 0;

var topArrow = document.getElementsByClassName("topArrow");
var menuText = document.getElementsByClassName("menuText");
var rightArrow = document.getElementsByClassName("rightArrow");
var bottomArrow = document.getElementsByClassName("bottomArrow");
var leftArrow = document.getElementsByClassName("leftArrow");

//assign navButtons to var buttons (creates array)
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("navButton");

//for each instance of buttons, assign class "active" onmouseover
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i){
    buttons[i].onmouseover = function() {
        this.className = "active";
        var arrow = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        console.log(arrow);
        console.log(topArrow);
        changeImages();
    }
}

//for each instance of buttons, remove class "active" onmouseout
for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; ++i){
    buttons[i].onmouseout = function () {
        this.className = "";
    };
}

function changeImages(){
    if ( arrow == topArrow ) {
        this.setAttribute("src", "images/arrows/top_o.png");
        console.log("arrow should change");
    } else {
        console.log("arrow should not change");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are redefining `arrow` in function scope, which is overshadowing global definition.

```
var arrow = 0;//global

var arrow = document.getElementsByClassName("active");// overshadowing assignment
```

Even if you fix is removing `var`, hence -

```
arrow = document.getElementsByClassName("active");// var removed
```

When you use `document.getElementByClassName`, you get an `HTMLCollection`, not that element even if there is one match. Matching array using `==` does not behave in the way you want.

To fix that use -

```
if(arrow[0] == toparrow[0])//assuming you have only one element with class 'active' and 'toparrow' in dom
```

Comment: Thanks.  so I have to drill down to the node of the element...

OR

how can I achieve a simple "if has this class then... else.."?

Comment: Looking better... but unfortunately I get "TypeError: arrow is null".  For console.log(arrow); I am seeing: HTMLCollection[img#topArrow.active images/a.../top.png], which is better than before.  console.log(topArrow); now returns the actual element:  "<img id="topArrow" class="active" src="images/arrows/top.png">".  

Not really sure where to go from here

Comment: is it possible to evaluate the attributes of the elements?

Comment: Can you post HTML too, would help a lot.

Comment: you are redefining arrow  in line number 54 `var arrow = document.getElementsByClassName("active");` just use `arrow = document.getElementsByClassName("active");` remove `var`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34488/discussion-between-vincentieo-and-moazzam-khan)